# sed: reversing pattern substitution

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I have the following `.txt` file:

```
ABC Corp
1234 7 Oaks Lane
Denton; TX 76509-4321
(682) 543-7890
```

I need to change the 4 last digit of the zip code in reverse using `sed` command. Example output:

```
ABC Corp
1234 7 Oaks Lane
Denton; TX 76509-1234
(682) 543-7890
```

It is the third line and has texts before the zip code and a dash in the middle.
So everything after the dash on third line. I only could of kind of do it when zip code is all by itself.
I tried:

```
sed -i -e 's/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])-([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])/\9\8\7\6/' test.txt
```

but this will remove everything else after reversing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your command first by looking for some pattern that is unique to the line. In the following example, we'll assume that the semi-colon `;` is unique (at least in your sample text) to the line to be parsed by `sed`:

```bsh
# capture the last 4 digits of the line and substitute them in reverse order
$ sed '/;/s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)$/\4\3\2\1/'
ABC Corp
1234 7 Oaks Lane 
Denton; TX 76509-1234
(682) 543-7890
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/633798/116858), but using Perl:

```
$ perl -lp -e '/;/ && s/(?<=-)\d{4}/reverse $&/e' <file
ABC Corp
1234 7 Oaks Lane
Denton; TX 76509-1234
(682) 543-7890
```

This finds lines containing a `;` character, and reverses the four digits after a dash on that line.

The reversal of the number is done using the Perl `reverse` function.

Answer (score 2):

Another `sed` alternative which is also flexible to reverse any length of digits:

```
sed -E ':a 3s/-([0-9]+)([0-9])$/-\2-\1/; ta;
        :b 3s/-([0-9])-([0-9]+)$/-\1\2/; tb'
```